# Failing to render base64 image return by async ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, knockout.js

I trying to make multiple async ajax call and one of it is to request base 64 image from server. It works for IE, Chrome and Firefox if i set the ajax request for base64 image to synchronous. However, for the case of asynchronous, the image is being rendered everytime in IE but not being rendered in Chrome and Firefox once in a while. Sometimes it is being rendered and sometimes it is not.
Most importantly, mobile browser do not render the image at ALL.

The code is pretty simple but I have no idea what's wrong with it.

```js
function TestViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.Image = ko.observable();
 
  
  self.GetProfileData = function () {
    $.ajax({
     async: true,
     type: 'GET',
     url: ..,
     success: {
        // return profile data
     }  
    });
  }
  
  self.GetProfileImage = function() {
    $.ajax({
       async: true, 
       type: 'GET',
       url: ..,
       success(data): {
        self.Image(data.Base64Image);
       }
    });
   }
  
  self.GetProfileData();
  self.GetProfileImage();
}

ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
```

```html
<img data-bind="attr: { src: Image }" alt="ProfileImage" />
```

Comment: Can you take the string being returned and place it in your browser address bar and successfully get the image.  It is possible there is something wrong with the base64 string itself.  The code looks correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use content type prefix:

```
self.Image("data:image/x;base64," + data.Base64Image);
```